# A question on the radial unit vector in polar coordinates

Tags: trigonometry

So, in polar coordinates $$r(t) = \cos(x) \hat{i}+\sin(x) \hat{j},$$ where $x$ is the angle from the beginning of the measurement.

I understand how this gives the correct unit vector when we measure along the $x$ axis of a circle measuring anti-clockwise. However, if you measure with the angle $x$ beginning along the y axis increasing in an anticlockwise fashion, then at some angle $x \in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$, $\cos(x) < 0$ and $\sin(x)  > 0$. This would give an $r(t)$ unit vector of some negative amount in the $\hat{i}$ direction along with some amount in the positive $\hat{j}$ direction.

However, surely we want $\cos(x)$ to be positive since we are in the top right hand quadrant. Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to measure like that? And if you do, just alter $x$ to $x-\pi/2$ in your formula and it would work perfectly.

In other words, to start measuring from the $y$-axis, define
$$
\begin{split}
r(t) &= \cos(x-\pi/2) \hat{i}+\sin(x-\pi/2) \hat{j} \\
     &= \sin(x) \hat{i}-\cos(x) \hat{j}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: It was a question where a car was projected inside a circular track anticlockwise starting from the bottom. I see what you mean, thanks